# How to iterate through an array of objects with a map function that has a conditional statement inside?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, conditional-statements

```js
const images = [
 {
    url: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/1000x671',
    text: 'hi'

  },
  {
    url: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/1000x671',
    text: 'hello'
  },
]

const Test = () => {
  const [on, toggle] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      {images.map((image, index) => (
        <div key={index} onClick={() => toggle(!on)}>
          {on && (
              {image.text}
          )}
          <img src={image.url} />
         </div>
      )}
    </div>
  )
};

export default Test;
```

I'm getting the img url to render correctly but img text is only showing the first object in the array and the only difference seems to be because it is within a conditional statement? Any ideas on what could be causing this issue. Thanks guys!

Comment: `{on && image.text}` is enough, no need to use the JSX syntax again since it's just valid JS already.

Answer (score 1):

Your jsx isn't valid, is that a typo in your post that doesn't exist in the code (note you have 3 opening `<div>`s, but only 2 closing `</div>`s)? For now I'm just going to assume that is the issue, try changing it to:

```
<div>
  {images.map((image, index) => (
    <div key={index} onClick={() => toggle(!on)}>
      {on && <div>{image.text}</div> }
      <img src={image.url} />
    </div>
  )}
</div>
```

Comment: I would assume that's an accident in the question since it would cause a syntax error and they claim they are just getting incorrect results.

Comment: yeah just a syntax error guys sorry about that,  just fixed it in the question

Comment: Please don't use answers to ask questions like that. Comments are meant for asking clarifying questions exactly like the one made in your answer. Then you can answer correctly, rather than making a guess.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is coming from the syntax you use to conditionally render the title.

```js
{on && ({image.text})}
```

It should just be `{on && image.text}`, unless you need to wrap it with another element like an `h1` or something `{on && <h1>{image.text}</h1>}`.

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

const images = [
  {
    url: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/1000x671',
    text: 'hi'

  },
  {
    url: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/1000x671',
    text: 'hello'
  }
];

const Test = () => {
  const [on, toggle] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      {images.map((image, index) => (
        <div key={index} onClick={() => toggle(!on)}>
          {on && image.text}
          <img src={image.url} />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
};

ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```